# Makefile compiling every time

Tags: c, makefile

I just started to learn the C programming language in my University. We have a task to create a Makefile that uses the executable program (battle in my case) and compiles only when is necessary. My problem with it is that it compiles every time I use the make command and it does not show "Is up to date" as I want to. I have 2 objects to compile (quest.o and thorgrim.o and only quest.o has to be created since we have the thorgrim.o already) into "battle". Here's my code:

```
CC=gcc
EXE=battle
CFLAGS=-Wall

build: run
run: quest.o
     $(CC) $^ thorgrim.o -o $(EXE)
     ./$(EXE)
quest.o: quest.c
     $(CC) -c $^ -o $@
clean: rm -rf quest.o $(EXE)
```

What am I doing wrong? I want it to compile once and then show up to date if I won't touch the quest.c.

Comment: Well, you run and link *in the same target*, so there's no way of doing one without the other. You might want to have a *compile* ← *link* ← *run* dependency instead.

Comment: Your problem: make goes to compile `run`, and assumes that `run` is an actual output file that the rule makes, not just something you made up. Hence, it doesn't find a file called `run`, and compiles.

Comment: You are my hero! After 7 hours this simple explanation was the only thing I needed. Our teacher told me is way too hard and I should ask on the forum of the University. Thanks again sir!

Comment: Add `.PHONY: build run`

Answer (score 3):

Seeing as you're new at this, I'll walk you through it, so you can learn to do it right the first time.   There's a lot of little details, that a lot of people end up missing, so hopefully this will give you a good reference:

First, lets start by defining your objects

```
OBJS := quest.o thorgrim.o
```

you can now create a pattern rule:

```
%.o: %.c
     $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -MD -MP $< -c -o $@
```

The first line of this rule `%.o:%.c` says that anything ending with a `.o` depends on a file with the same name ending in `.c`.   Doing this prevents you from from having to write a separate rule for every object file.   Notice that there is a default pattern rule to this effect, but we'll not go into that here.

Next, you call `$(CC)` with `$(CFALGS)`.   Notice that `$@` now represents the name of the .o file you are generating, and `$<` represents the first dependency of the object (the .c file in this case).

The `-MD` and `-MP` are used to automatically generate dependency files -- for each `.c` file it will also create a `.d` file, which lists the dependencies (`.h` files) that your source requires to build.   You have to `-include` the dependency files for it to work.  (see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.1/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html for more details on exactly what these do).    This way, if you modify a header file, it will automatically rebuild the necessary `.o` files.   Having said that, you have to include those .d files in your makefile:

```
-include $(OBJS:.o=.d)
```

This will include the .d files as if someone cut and paste the code into your makefile.     The `$(OBJS:.o=.d)` simply tells make to take the variable `OBJS` and replace all the `.o`'s with `.d`'s.   Notice the `-` before the include.  This tells make not to worry if the file doesn't exist (as will be the case on your first build ...).

Ok, now that you've got your .o files built, you need to build your program:

```
$(EXE): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $^ -o $@
```

Add a default rule and comments, and you're done.   So, in summary, your makefile will look something like:

```
CC:=gcc
EXE:=battle
CFLAGS:=-Wall
OBJS:=quest.o thorgrim.o

%.o: %.c
     $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -MD -MP $< -c -o $@

$(EXE): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $^ -o $@

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) $(EXE)

-include $(OBJS:.o=.d)
```

EDIT: forgot the clean rule -- adding that.

Comment: as I understood the original task was to execute `battle` (and rebuild if needed). In such case we will need add default target `run: $(EXE)` `          ./$(EXE)` (as told in other comment above)

Comment: Yes... I didn't include that.  I don't like the practice of having makefiles run end programs -- that's the job of a script (or the program itself...).   If you wanted to do a one liner you could run `make && ./battle`

Answer (score 1):

The run target depends on files, but the build rule does not produce a file named 'run'. A better idea is to do something along these lines:

```
run: $(EXE)
     ./$(EXE)

$(EXE): $(OBJ)
       $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $+
```

Comment: I have done what you suggested but without any luck. It runs corectly but still compiles. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing it properly.
Here's a "Makefile template":

```
CC=gcc
none: prog  #`make` -> `make prog`

#make's default rules are fine here.
prog: foo.o bar.o

foo.o: foo.c head.h

bar.o: bar.c head.h
```

**EDIT**: You need to use `whatever.o`, *not* `whatever` for object files, so make knows to pass `-c`.

Comment: I can't have more than those 2 object files and I wouldn't know how to use those headers. Thanks!

Comment: replace `foo` and `bar` with the appropriate filenames. Adding a header to a target just tells make that it needs to recompile if it's changed. You don't need them.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: added $(EXE) as dependency to `run` target

the following makefile shows how it should be written

When generating any macro, those resulting contents will not change, always use `:=` rather than `=` so the macro is only evaluated once

When generating a macro for an executable, always include the full path to the executable, so the right executable is always executed, irregardless of other changes to your system and/or environment 'PATH'

Note: however, to have multiple files in a executable, to be able to communication between the files, there should be one header file for each source file those contents need to be exposed (data and functions and data types)  Then those header files need to be listed in the dependencies when compiling.

```
CC := /usr/lib/gcc
RM := /usr/lib/rm -f -r

EXE := battle
CFLAGS := -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -std=gnu99 -c

# macro with all the source names
SRCS := thorgrim.c quest.c

# macro with all the object file names
OBJS := $(SRCS:.c=.o)

# always include a .PHONY statement for any targets
# that do not produce a file of the same name
.PHONY : all clean run

# 'all' is the typical first target
all: run

# implied compile rule/recipe
%.o:%.c
<tab>$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<

# the macro 'LFLAGS' is part of the default macros
# link the objects into an executable
$(EXE): $(OBJS)
<tab>$(CC) $^ -o $@ $(LFLAGS)

# execute the executable
run: $(EXE)
<tab>./$(EXE)


clean: 
<tab>$(RM) quest.o $(EXE)
```

Note: replace the `<tab>` with an actual tab character

Comment: A couple of quick comments: hardcoding an absolute path can make the code less portable (other people may install their tools in other places, or they may WANT to use the gcc that's in their path rather than the default one...).   For the rm, you should likely `$(RM) $(OBJS) $(EXE)`, and skip the `-r` unless necessary.   The `run` rule should likely depend ond the `$(EXE)`.

Comment: no, the first target should not depend on the `$(EXE)` because the OP wants to execute the program.  regarding the `-r`, the OP used it, and I see no reason to not follow the OPs lead when possible.  I do agree that it is not necessary in the current scenario

Comment: NOT coding the path to the desired system utility will result in which version of the utility being executed will depend on the `PATH` environment variable.   This can/will lead to a major problem when other tool sets are available via the `PATH` environment variable as which one will be used will depend on the order of the entries in the variable.  It is a bad idea to depend on the `PATH` environment variable when producing portable code.